# How to make clickable the included button inside my drawer layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

**I want to click the button included inside my drawer layout. How do i make it?**

**this is the xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".main.views.MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/activity_home"></include>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ts_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemIconSize="35dp"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: Huh weird. I don't see any buttons though...

Comment: my buttin inside of included layout

Comment: this is the xml code of  included layout

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_create_order"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_create_order"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Answer (score 0):

```
val navView = findViewbyId(R.id.nav_View)
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.YOUR_ID -> {
            //click
        }
    }

    true
}
```

Comment: still not clickable

Comment: this is the xml code of included layout
     <Button android:id="@+id/btn_create_order" android:layout_width="350dp" 
     android:layout_height="60dp" android:text="@string/btn_create_order" 
     android:textSize="17sp" android:textStyle="bold" app:cornerRadius="50dp" 
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" 
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is an example in java:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_create_order);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_create_order: 
                //Do something...
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: still not clickable

Comment: If you copy that piece of code and paste it in your ``MainActivity.java`` file, inside ``onCreate()`` method, it should work.